# Example of Symplectic fibration

Tags: symplectic-geometry, fibration

Can you give a example of manifold $M$ such that $\pi:M\longrightarrow T^2 $ be a Symplectic fibration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any symplectic manifold. Then there is a symplectic fibration given by $M = X \times T^{2}$ with the map $f: X \times T^{2} \rightarrow T^{2}$ given by projection to the second factor.